# Code always returning else statement

Tags: ruby

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def factor(number, number1)

    remainder = number % number1
    print "The remainder is #{remainder}"
    if  remainder == 0

        puts "#{number} is a factor of #{number1}"

    else

        puts "#{number} is not a factor of #{number1}"      
    end

end 

puts 

print "Enter the number : "
number=gets.chomp
print "Enter the number to check for its factor : "
number1=gets.chomp

factor(number,number1)

$end
```

Comment: `gets.chomp.to_i`? You can't take the modulo of strings

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I didn't read about it :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the input strings when calling **gets.chomp**  to numbers, and then call the method like this.

```
puts

print "Enter the number : "
number=gets.chomp.to_i
print "Enter the number to check for its factor : "
number1=gets.chomp.to_i

factor(number,number1)
```